# How to plot data in format HH:MM:SS greater than 24H useing seaborn package

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

is there a method to format the x-axis in HH:MM:SS format? My data is measurements at an interval of 5 minutes for 72H. I would like the x-axis description to represent only 00:00:00, 12:00:00, 24:00:00, 36:00:00, 48:00:00, 60:00:00, 72:00:00. The result increases with each measurement

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
act = pd.read_csv('act pH 1-10.xlsx.csv')
g = sns.lineplot(x='Time', y='YAKE_1 pH7',  data=act)
plt.show()

# example of df 

| Time | YAKE_1 pH7 |
| --- | --- |
| 24:00:00 | 0,598 |
| 24:10:00 | 0,624 |
| 24:20:00 | 0,625 |
| 24:30:00 | 0,645 |
........
| Time | YAKE_1 pH7 |
| --- | --- |
| 71:50:00 | 1,625 |
| 72:00:00 | 1,645 |
```

output of plot

[image]

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('act pH 1-10.xlsx.csv', decimal=',')` must be used to correctly read the numeric values as floats.

Comment: Plot with `df.plot(x='Time', y='YAKE_1 pH7')`

Comment: For the timedelta approach, there's a helper function `df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)`, but that includes a "days" portion for >24 hours. It gets trickier if you want a pure `HH:MM:SS` format without "days" at all.

Comment: @tdy I haven't seen `to_timedelta`. That's much better than trying to use `pd.Timedelta` (deleted my previous comments using it).